# C# Preventing ConnectionStringBuilder from escaping password with equal sign

Tags: c#, odbc, database-connection, string-literals

I have a password that I can't change that has an equal sign in it. When using `OdbcConnectionStringBuilder` it works for passwords that don't have a equal sign, but when I do it escapes the variable. This works,

```
        builder.DataSourceName = "SERVER";
        builder.DatabaseFile = "THISSERV";
        builder.UserID = "DBA";
        builder.Password = "XU5%^YhZ";
```

And produces the following connection string

`"UserID=DBA;Password=XU5%^YhZ;DatabaseFile=THISSERV;DataSourceName=SERVER"`

However, if you put in an equal sign

```
        builder.DataSourceName = "SERVER";
        builder.DatabaseFile = "THISSERV";
        builder.UserID = "DBA";
        builder.Password = "XU5%^Yh=Z";
```

It produces the following connection string with the password escaped.

`"UserID=DBA;Password=\"XU5%^Yh=Z\";DatabaseFile=THISSERV;DataSourceName=SERVER"`

How can I avoid this? The previous example is correct, but in my application I am actually decrypting the password as well, which doesn't affect anything if there isn't an equal, I tried putting the @ in front of StringCipher, but it didn't work. It would look like this with the first argument actually being a variable.

```
builder.Password = StringCipher.Decrypt("0jURE7f9aTOItD5tgl9E6YoBKhMRaxDVj1KfS0SJ/ZBxIKVVbVYZXHMKgndI", "JlkIUJdfolsdff352345rf")
```

Comment: I suspect you mean the `ConnectionStringBuilder`?

Comment: Yes, sorry I meant to say that.

Comment: I had to just not use ConnectionStringBuilder and concatenate it manually myself.

Comment: @Alan consider [edit]ing your question to correct that mistake.

Comment: This seems the correct behaviour, since this is a list of *name=value* items, so the location of equals signs within the connectionstring is.important: if it does not quote the value containing the equals sign, it could be misinterpreted. I think this is an XY problem. Why do you care? I'm guessing you have something else which reads that value, but doesn't parse it correctly. *That* is the problem you should be fixing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to surround the password in curly brackets `{ }` as per the [Odbc ConnectionString escape guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.odbc.odbcconnection.connectionstring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_Odbc_OdbcConnection_ConnectionString):

> A DSN or connection string value enclosed with braces ({}) that
>   contains any of the characters []{}(),;?*=!@ is passed intact to the
>   driver.

So calling it like this should work:

```
builder.Password = "{XU5%^Yh=Z}";
```